# Uniform auto items height in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page with a flex box and multiple flex items, flex items represent posts, those posts sometimes have large titles and sometimes small ones resulting in a non uniform height per row, as you may see in this image:

[image: page]

I don't want to set a fixed height because now small titles will have a big empty space. Rather, I want the height to be constant per row and is equal to the least height possible to contain the post elements.

Here is my Css:

```
/* Post Pages */

.post-containter {
    padding:4%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: space-around;
}
.post {
    text-align: center;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: thin solid #f8f8f8;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    transition: box-shadow 150ms ease-in-out;
}
.post h5 {
    font-weight: normal;
    margin:5px;
}
.post:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
.posts-head {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 50px;
}
img.post-image {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 3px solid #558abb;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00c8bd;
}
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="post-containter">
{% for post in site.posts %}
    <a href="{{post.url}}">
        <div class="post">
            <img class="post-image" src="{{ post.image_path }}" alt="{{ post.title }}"/>
            <h5>{{ post.title }}</h5>
        </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Site reference: https://squircleart.github.io/posts.html

Comment: You can try justify-content: stretch; and work with margins for the posts.

Comment: We need to see HTML and CSS for the elements inside as well, as for me the `post` for sure have the same size, but its content doesn't

Comment: @Gerard `justify-content` doesn't have a value of `stretch`

Comment: @LGSon Can I post the site itself?https://squircleart.github.io/posts.html

Comment: Yes you can, as a reference, though the question should have the enough to show the issue, so it needs an update too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is the parent element of the `post`, the link that wraps it.

If you give it `display: flex` it will work

```
.post-containter > a {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Would it be better if I used the post class in the "a" tag instead of the div?

Comment: @OmarAhmad Can't say, try it out and see, and if you get into trouble, you know where to ask :). At least now you know what's causing it.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working fine. I just had to add text-decoration: none; to make sure my title doesn't have underlines.