# Height issue with 4 column grid alignment in css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem is want to make even height for all columns, if i'm using various contents for each columns. I want to know how to fix the even height for 4 columns. I've tried to fix the height all columns with all the device models but some device would be aligned properly, rest of the devices not aligned. Can you please suggest me where I made mistake in my code?

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>NXT-255</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="header">
        <h1>This is test</h1>
        <p>description description description</p>
    </div>

    <div class="features">
        <div class="item">
            <h1>This is test</h1>
            <p>description description description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1>This is test</h1>
            <p>description description description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <h1>This is test</h1>
            <p>description description description</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</body1>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.header{
    float: left;
    min-height: 260px;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 20%;
}
div.features{
    display: flex;
    min-height: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

div.features .item{
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 20%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 920px) and (max-width: 1240px){
        div.header{
        float: left;
        min-height: 260px;
        background-color: yellow;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 33%;
            }
    div.features{
        display: flex;
        min-height: 260px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lightblue;
            }

    div.features .item{
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width: 33%;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 620px) and (max-width: 919px){
        div.header{
        float: left;
        min-height: 260px;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 33%;
            }
    div.features{
        display: flex;
        min-height: 260px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lightblue;
            }

    div.features .item{
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width: 33%;
        }
    }

@media screen and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 619px){
        div.header{
        float: left;
        min-height: 260px;
        background-color: green;
        padding: 10px;
        width: 33%;
            }
    div.features{
        display: flex;
        min-height: 260px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: lightblue;
            }

    div.features .item{
        flex: 1;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        width: 33%;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS only solution to set MULTIPLE “same height” row sections on a responsive grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44129135/css-only-solution-to-set-multiple-same-height-row-sections-on-a-responsive-gri)

Comment: Another possible duplicate [Uniform auto items height in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563785/uniform-auto-items-height-in-flexbox)

Comment: Actually, the problem is how to wrap the content into block eventhough, the each block have various content. how to even the height for all blocks?

Comment: If i'm adding display:flex property, it will not work. I know how to wrap that based on break points but i don't want to align for each break points.

Comment: Then you'll need script ... or maybe CSS Grid can do it

Comment: I hope that, if the blocks are wrap into one block, it will work. But I've two kind of blocks. I hope  you already seen my code. For instance: "header" & "features" divs

Comment: Do you talk about the gray left should have same height as the 3 light blue?

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: Setting `display: flex` on the `row` and remove `float` on the `header` does that, so is this want you want: https://jsfiddle.net/8xg9L698/

Comment: thanks buddy. My expectation done. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As comments can be deleted I posted that as an answer, and please accept it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `display: flex` on the `row` will solve that, and then you can remove `float` on the `header` as it doesn't do anything anymore.

```css
div.row {
  display: flex;
}
div.header {
  min-height: 260px;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 20%;
}

div.features {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 260px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

div.features .item {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 20%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 920px) and (max-width: 1240px) {
  div.header {
    float: left;
    min-height: 260px;
    background-color: yellow;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 33%;
  }
  div.features {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  div.features .item {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 33%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 620px) and (max-width: 919px) {
  div.header {
    float: left;
    min-height: 260px;
    background-color: gray;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 33%;
  }
  div.features {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  div.features .item {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 33%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 520px) and (max-width: 619px) {
  div.header {
    float: left;
    min-height: 260px;
    background-color: green;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 33%;
  }
  div.features {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 260px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  div.features .item {
    flex: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    width: 33%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="header">
    <h1>This is test</h1>
    <p>description description description</p>
  </div>

  <div class="features">
    <div class="item">
      <h1>This is test</h1>
      <p>description description description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>This is test</h1>
      <p>description description description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h1>This is test</h1>
      <p>description description description</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```